# Can we please delete the high-school tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This is one of those "meta" tags.

Currently there are 31 questions with this tag: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school

There are 4-5 questions which specifically talk about high school, but I believe they can do without that tag.

If we keep the tag around, I predict many questions will get this tag just because the asker is a high-school student and will be practically useless (if there was any use of it in the first place...).

Comment: Shouldn't this be merged into the "Tag merging ..." thread?

Comment: @Asaf: I was under the impression that that thread is for tags already merged? Or are we supposed to propose stuff there? Also, do we talk of tag deletes there?

Comment: I also use it for deletion suggestions as well. I guess one of the moderators will give us the "correct" answer...

Comment: @Asaf: Based on the summary thread, it does look like deletes make their appearance there.

Comment: Huh, something happened to my ability to delete tags. Haven't used it in a while....

Comment: Noooo! The tag deletion powers have been deleted, and I didn't even know! (It has been gone since forever, apparently.)

Comment: @Asaf Aryabhata: guys, we're going to have to go in and do them by hand. (By "we" I mean "you" and don't do them all at once so we don't flood the front page.)

Comment: @Willie: I'm not sure I have the mental capabilities of doing that, you should file a complaint with Jeff about that. I believe that a moderator should be able to delete tags when needed.

Comment: Hey, wait a minute! Hasn't there been enough retagging for today?

Comment: Ah @Theo, so you want to join in on the fun too, eh? `=)` But given that Aryabhata and I have just done a half dozen. Maybe we should pause a bit.

Comment: @Willie: No I don't! About half my frontpage is filled with tag-edit posts, that's more than enough (I use 50 posts per page, usually). Also I think that this decision was taken and implemented a bit quickly... What's up with all this nonsense on meta-tags anyway? I never got that.

Comment: @Theo: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/. Even though it might seem stack overflow specific, it has points which are relevant to math.se.

Comment: @Theo: unfortunately, not everyone is as diligent as you are in catching mis-used tags when they occur, so sometimes it is more efficient to batch them (that's what happened earlier when I retagged a bunch of probability theory questions that were tagged (distribution-theory)). There are other reasons that I am against the (high-school) tag, it being a meta-tag is just one aspect. I'll write an answer later tonight, if I have some time.

Comment: (Basically, the (high-school) tag is US-centric, contains minimum amount of useful information, all of which should instead be included in the Question Statement rather than as a tag anyway, and it tends to frame the answer given not based on the mathematical sophistication of the question asker, but based on the answerer's own high school education.)

Comment: @Theo: You can also sort the front page by 'newest' rather than 'active'. I guess it comes in handy during these tag-edit situations...

Comment: @Willie, Aryabhata: Thanks for all that information. I'm really not convinced by that reasoning of Jeff's. Okay, we can try to classify tags from more specific to less specific. We don't want too specific ones and we don't want too broad ones. But where's the boundary? How is (number-theory), (probability) or (category-theory), let alone (philosophy) or (education), so much more specific than (high-school)?

Comment: @Theo It is not so much that (high-school) is broad; it is more that (a) there is no clear definition of high school, whereas there are clear definitions of what number-theory etc. are, and a reasonably clear "I can call it when I see it" working description of philosophy and education. (b) Why should the fact that the question is encountered by a high-school student have any bearing on the question? The only answer I have to that question is for the users to address the answer to an appropriate level. But there is such a spread between say Stuy in NYC and some inner city school in Baltimore

Comment: that it is rather meaninless to use (high-school) tag to decide. It'd be much better for all parties involved to approach the answer not from some pre-conceived notion of what high-school is like, but from the mathematical maturity demonstrated by the individual in asking that question. (cf. point (a)). (c) I don't see how the high-school tag can be useful in organization or searches. Whereas an appropriate subject tag (even one like education) can help focus in on questions when certain keywords used in the search has multiple uses in different fields.

Comment: @Willie: Thanks a lot for that. Your next-to-last comment seems to have made something click (I like to imagine that I'm usually not that dense...) I'll need to meditate a little bit about these points. No need for further discussion and elaboration at the moment, let's go and focus on more important and interesting issues! -- btw. I myself never used the tagging system for anything else than for the sake of attaching the appropriate tag so that it may be helpful for others, hopefully. The search-thing here is so "intelligent" that it is of absolutely no use to me.

Comment: I have no problem with the tag being deleted, but *please* get it deleted the proper batch way, not with manual editing.

Comment: @Isaac: Was that addressed to the Mods? btw, What is the batch way?

Comment: @Isaac: I am informed that the "proper" way is no longer possible.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: In that case, I'd say that the "new proper" way would be to go into the mod chat and look for an SE employee who can actually do the deletion.  If we (the SE network overall) do that enough that it annoys them, they might put the feature back.  If we don't do it enough to annoy them, then they were probably right to remove the feature.

Comment: @Aryabhata: It was intended to be openly addressed—as a not-quite-answer to the original question, as a note to non-mods suggesting that this not be done by regular editing, and possibly as a note to the mods to do it via the batch way that apparently no longer exists.

Comment: @qia we can delete tags at will, but it is a developer level operation. I strongly suggest feeding the tag deletion request to a developer (Rebecca counts)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Trogdor is pure awesome.

Comment: I think we need to blacklist the tag too. I suppose deletion would probably do a blacklist too...

Comment: @aryabhata if it recurs reply here and we'll take action at that time

Answer (score 4):

[high-school](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school) reappeared here (in December 2013): https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/617787/revisions

Feel free to edit this answer if you see this tag again - if the tag will be occurring repeatedly, we can request blacklisting.

Answer (score -4):

With the coronavirus lockdown and closing of many schools in different countries isn't there a case, at least temporarily, for a way of identifying high-school questions very clearly so that the level of mathematical maturity is identified and they can invite sympathetic responses which will help enthusiastic young mathematicians to learn, and get excited by, mathematics?

It would be useful to have an agreed protocol and discussion given the controversies which arise.

Comment: "High school" does not have a consistent meaning across the globe, and "high school" is not a branch of mathematics nor a meaningful description of any kind of mathematical curriculum.  I don't think that I understand how a "high school" tag would help to organize the site.

Comment: Answer to your question: yes! I think it's a good idea. This way, for example, one can have for sure that a question say tagged as `high-school` and `calculus` will be about the  calculus taught at a high school level and not the calculus taught at the university level (which is basically only about theorems and proofs)

Comment: @Bellatrix Having taught both high school and college level calculus, I don't see much of a distinction between the two (other than noting that the high school curriculum moves more slowly).  I have had the same experience with high school and college level precalculus / trigonometry classes.  Again, "high school" tag doesn't meaningfully sort posts.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ah. Then I think that it depends on where one is. In some places, even if you’re not studying mathematics, say you’re in the engineer or computer science, etc. the calculus classes are very difficult and it’s by no means like the calculus taught at high school.

Comment: @Bellatrix That is exactly the point I was attempting to make in my original comment:  "High school" does not have a consistent meaning across the globe, and "high school" is not a branch of mathematics nor a meaningful description of any kind of mathematical curriculum.  I should also note that my second comment refers to the fact that I have taught courses in US middle schools, high schools, and post-secondary institutions (as the US is most definitely not the rest of the world).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Well "Pre-university" then, or something - my suggestion (from UK) is that there might be some chance of supporting young aspiring mathematicians in the weird world we now inhabit.

Comment: You seem to make the assumption that a high-school question will necessarily be frowned upon because of its low mathematical level. Not true. The problem lies in questions with no context or no attempt, and with or without the tag, they are not acceptable here. A good high-school question is as good here as a good university question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Not so much that, more that answers which include more coaching and placing mathematical ideas in a wider context would be particularly appreciated. But also - certainly in the UK - the nature of "homework" has changed entirely for the duration, and some of the more abrupt responses to poorer questions might be discouraged. So yes, a little relaxation on some questions on the basis that learning to ask a good question taels time. A further point is that young people asking for the first time might not be so familiar with mathematical typesetting.